# insert not working in jsp with msaccess

Tags: jsp, ms-access

i am new in jsp and i used this code to insert data into msaccess table
i got problem that when i click submit button after filing all required field the page should redirect to quiz.jsp. but it is not happening and noting inserted to the db too.

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
   if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
 {
Connection conn=null;
Statement stmt=null;
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:biplob");
try{
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String quest = request.getParameter("quest").toString();
String QA = request.getParameter("QA").toString();
String QB = request.getParameter("QB").toString();
String QC = request.getParameter("QC").toString();
String QD = request.getParameter("QD").toString();
String correctAns = request.getParameter("correctAns").toString();
       out.println("quest : " + quest);

   String qry = "insert into quiz(quest,QA,QB,QC,QD,correctAns)values('"+quest+"','"+QA+"','"+QB+"','"+QC+"','"+QD+"','"+correctAns+"')";

     out.println("qry : " + qry);

int val = st.executeUpdate(qry);

    if(val>0)
    {
      response.sendRedirect("quiz.jsp");
    }
con.close();
   }

   catch(SQLException ex){
System.out.println("SQL satatment not found");
   }
   }
   catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   %>
```

pls help me wih this .. where is wrong in this code .

Comment: Have you tried to replace single quotes with double quotes in the SQL string?

Comment: Are you sure your code get into the If statement ("submit")!=null)?

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso: i think so

Answer (score 1):

You have kept one extra closing brace. I think it will work if you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Scriplets are really bad practice in jsp , you should avoid using it . The workflow you mentioned can entirely done without scriplet . Insert data to the db from servlet instead.

Do it in that way and if you would face any problems ask it here at SO. See [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL satatment not found");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

by

```
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

To get a detailed error report complete with the root cause exception, its message and the full stacktrace. It contains the answer.